# Use a default/fallback value if the translation is not available in Lingui, React

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, linguijs

I have the following code:

```
  const message = msg({
    context: "test",
    id: "username",
    message: t`Your name is: ${name}`,
  });
```

The problem is that when I run `npm run messages:extract` if the translation is not available for the selected langugae it only returns the `id` instead of using `message` as some sort of default value.

Also, how should I render message?

```
<>{i18n._(tesztuzenet)}</>
```

or

```
<>{message.message}</>
```

Are there any differences?